# why doesn't latex start a new page when showing multiple figures

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{ccc}

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Alexis_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Alexis_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Alexis_view1.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Alexis_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Alexis_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Alexis_view2.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Hongzhu_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Hongzhu_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Hongzhu_view1.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Hongzhu_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Hongzhu_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Hongzhu_view2.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Kiki_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Kiki_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Kiki_view1.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Kiki_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Kiki_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Kiki_view2.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Liang_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Liang_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Liang_view1.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Liang_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Liang_view2.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Liang_view2.png} \\

\includegraphics[width=2in]{stick/Miao_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk/Miao_view1.png}&
\includegraphics[width=2in]{sdk_extension/Miao_view1.png}

\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Latex==>PDF
I'm using the above code to show multiple figures. But latex only prints one page and ignores other figures.

Can anyone explain it and help me solve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Converting comment to an answer:

You have placed all your figures in a single `array`. 
The `array` environment can't span multiple pages, and assuming that your images have a height that does not allow them to fit on one page, the remainder of the `array` is truncated.

You could try using `longtable` instead, which is a multi-page version of `tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

As @PeterGrill mentioned you could use a multi-page table construct such as `longtable` but do you need a table at all. If you took your example and deleted

```
$
\begin{array}{ccc}


\end{array}
$
```

Then deleted every `&` and `\\` it would work, as each group of three images would form a paragraph so line up horizontally and then the blank line between each group would start a new paragraph so force a line break.

Comment: You might only need to start your figure with the `\noindent` command in some cases.

Comment: well yes perhaps in general, although the MWE is using center so `\noindent` has no visible effect here.

Comment: That's why I added "in some cases", in the sake of completeness ;)